# Reading integers from an unorganized text file

Tags: c++, fstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype> // isdigit();
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("Sayı.txt");
    while (!fin.eof()){
        string word;
        int n;
        fin >> word;  //First i read it as a string.
        if (isdigit(word[0])){ //checks whether is it an int or not
            fin.unget(); //
            fin >> n;  // if its a int read it as an int
            cout << n << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Suppose the text file is something like this:

```
100200300 Glass
Oven 400500601
```

My aim is simply to read integers from that text file and show them in console.
So the output should be like

```
100200300
400500601
```

You can see my attempt above.As output i get only the last digit of integers.Here's a sample output:

```
0
1
```

Comment: What do you think `unget()` is doing? Perhaps look at the documentation.

Comment: [`while (!eof())` is wrong.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: unget() drops the temporarily stored variable on fin.Or thats what i think it does.

Comment: It doesn't. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple just try converting the string read to an int using string streams, if it fails then it isn't an integer , otherwise it is an integer.

```
 ifstream fin;
    istringstream iss;
    fin.open("Say1.txt");

    string word;
    while (fin>>word )
    {

        int n=NULL;        
        iss.str(word);

        iss>>n;

        if (!iss.fail())
        cout<<n<<endl;

        iss.clear();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should do what you want (untested code):

```
int c;
while ((fin >> std::ws, c = fin.peek()) != EOF)
{
  if (is_digit(c))
  {
    int n;
    fin >> n;
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    std::string s;
    fin >> s;
  }
}
```